# Can i run tensorflow lite object detection in background as a service

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, background-application

I'm using a example of tensorflow lite object detection give on their official site, i need to run the app as a service in background to provide some data (like the location of detections) to another app that will be running normally (the user will use this app to do what he have to do, and my another application will provide data in background for some case of use for this main application)
My question is: is that possible? In case, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special in TFLite in terms of running it in an Android Service. Note that background services are not expected to consume significant resources, therefore your service will be a foreground service.